# Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 587

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm getting this error in development when trying to create a user. Who can enlighten me what have I done wrong?

[image]

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver_now
      redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user.id), notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

**environments/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  adress: "smtp@gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

**mailers/application_mailer.rb**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "alexnotonfire@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

**mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.signup_confirmation.subject
  #
  def signup_confirmation(user)
    @user = user

    mail to: user.email, subject: "Sign Up Confirmation"
  end
end
```

**views/user_mailer/signup_confirmation.text.erb**

```
<%= @user.first_name %>,

Thank you for signing up!
```

Comment: You have a typo in your config - `adress` - and the address you've provided isn't a valid SMTP address anyway.

Comment: Use [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) instead of Gmail for your development environment.

Comment: @max Thanks, I'll try in a little bit.

Comment: This `adress: "smtp@gmail.com"` should be `address: "smtp.gmail.com"`

Comment: @Pavan It's making progress. Now I'm having another error.

Answer (score 1):

Connection is getting refused by gmail while attempting to deliver the mail. I had almost the same issue and lately I found out that I have not enabled telnet client on my system which ping gmail. So I have enabled telnet client on my system (Windows 7). Also run a telnet test to troubleshoot the connection. I have followed this link [http://techblissonline.com/troubleshoot-gmail-smtp-server-connection/]http://techblissonline.com/troubleshoot-gmail-smtp-server-connection/ to carry out telnet test.  If you are able to ping gmail and still you are getting error, then go to gmail settings and allow less secure apps to access your account.

Comment: you may try port 465 and 25.Check which port works for you.

Comment: Actually now I'm having another trouble. It says "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required". But thanks for explanation

Comment: Pavan is right. the address should be `"smtp.gmail.com"` and please correct the typos in the config file.

Comment: To resolve "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required" issue, you need to follow the last line in answer. Basically changing the gmail settings to be accessed by low secure apps. To find out how, check this [https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: Yep, but that is not enough. I resolved the problem.